# Flutter not connecting with cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to build a Flutter app with Cloud Firestore backend. I have been able to successfully set it up with auth so that I am able sign in. However, I have not been able to successfully read and write to the cloud firestore database. I have the latest Cloud Firestore plugin in my Pubspec.yaml and my security rules are off, so I am a little confused why it is not working? Here is an example of a button trying to write to the database.

```
onPressed: () {
              print("running");
              Firestore.instance
                  .collection('tasks')
                  .add({
                "title": "PJ",
                "description": "PJ",
              }).catchError((err) => print(err));
              print("running2");

            },
```

Anyone have any idea as to what might be the issue or how I can troubleshoot?

Comment: no errors? and are you sure you are not in real-time database page instead of cloud firestore ?